# Css bug only occurs when external monitor is connected

Tags: css, google-chrome

I get this gray field showing when i scroll in the div.

It started happening recently and I have not updated the app since it started happening.

It only shows when:

- In chrome
- When external monitor is connected. In laptop it does happen when in mirror mode with external monitor but not when disconnected.

I can't select the gray field in the selector. It's as its not there.

Is it a bug in chrome? How do I debug this?

[image]

**Update**
I'm using this template http://triangular.oxygenna.com/#!/elements/lists
Same error occurs on that page.

Comment: sounds more like a graphics driver issue to me

Comment: Could you share some code to reproduce this issue?

Comment: @JeremyThille . Yes, sounds likely.

Comment: @Huelfe. Yes. I've updated the question.